# 2D Python List for a lottery program

Tags: python, list, 2d

im creating a lotto program where it draws 8 numbers and check for whether they match with the 100 lotto players numbers. i have created the part where i randomly generate 8 number and store them on a list but i dont know how to create a 2D list in python to store the users randomly generated numbers with their ID's

For Example the 2D list should look something like this

```
Player ID | PlayerNumber
 1        | 2 3 4 5 6 7 4 23
 2        | 14 12 14 30 0 13 25
 3        | 21 30 2 22 23 14 19 12
 4        | 21 12 22 30 24 25 28 15
```

```
8 numbers winning numbers are from a pool of 0 - 30 numbers
the Player ID pool is 1 - 100 meaning 100 players
the Lotto number pool is 0 - 30
```

the part that i have created draws the 8 winning numbers but i dont know how to create the above table

```
import random

def generateRandomNumber():
    randomNumber = random.randint(0,30) #can return numbers between 0 and 30 including 0 and 30
    return randomNumber#return Random numbers

def drawWinningLotteryNumber():#this function draws the winning numbers
    lotteryDrawNumbers = []#list containner for the generated lottery numbers
    for currentLotteryNumber in range(8):#for loop to keep generating for 8 counts
        randomNumber = generateRandomNumber()# call funtion to generate random numbers
        lotteryDrawNumbers.append(randomNumber)# add to the back of the list

    return lotteryDrawNumbers#return the list
    
def printWinningLotteryNumber(lotteryDrawNumbers):#ths function prints the draw numbers
    for currentLotteryNumberIndex in range (len(lotteryDrawNumbers)):#for loop to run the print funtion for the length of the list
        print(lotteryDrawNumbers[currentLotteryNumberIndex], end = " ")#prints the numbers

def draw():# this funtion brings to gether the draw funtion
    
    lotteryNumbers = drawWinningLotteryNumber()#call function to draw winning numbers
    print ("The 8 lottery number for today are :")
    printWinningLotteryNumber(lotteryNumbers)#call funtion to print the generated numbers

def generateID():#this function creates the lotto players and their numbers
    i = 0
    players = []

    for currentPlayers in range(100):
        i = i + 1
        players.append(i)

    for currentPlayerIndex in range(len(players)):
        print(players[currentPlayerIndex])

generateID()

draw()
```

Comment: You can use list of lists like this: `[[ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 23], [...], [...]]`. Or use `np.array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionnary `players` to associate an ID with a list of numbers. Try this :

```
def generateID():#this function creates the lotto players and their numbers
    players = {}

    for player_id in range(1, 11):
        player_list = []
        for i in range(8):
            player_list.append(generateRandomNumber())
        players[player_id] = player_list

    for player_id in players:
        print("Player {} has numbers {}".format(player_id, players[player_id]))
```

Output :

```
Player 1 has numbers [24, 23, 29, 16, 14, 1, 24, 0]
Player 2 has numbers [13, 7, 13, 8, 11, 2, 14, 11]
Player 3 has numbers [1, 17, 2, 30, 8, 10, 6, 18]
Player 4 has numbers [23, 0, 0, 9, 15, 12, 5, 20]
Player 5 has numbers [7, 5, 1, 0, 13, 10, 8, 11]
Player 6 has numbers [24, 6, 2, 15, 18, 9, 6, 29]
Player 7 has numbers [17, 9, 3, 30, 29, 28, 5, 19]
Player 8 has numbers [23, 30, 9, 12, 23, 19, 15, 5]
Player 9 has numbers [15, 11, 3, 22, 20, 6, 24, 4]
Player 10 has numbers [14, 29, 6, 13, 22, 11, 25, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
from random import choices

number_of_players = 4

draws = [choices(range(0, 30), k=8) for _ in range(number_of_players)]

print("Player ID | Draw")
for player_id, draw in enumerate(draws, start=1):
    print(f"{player_id:<10}|", *draw)
```

Output:

```
Player ID | Draw
1         | 6 1 5 9 16 29 12 17
2         | 25 21 8 22 5 10 28 26
3         | 8 1 18 6 18 20 1 0
4         | 28 9 28 2 21 23 17 1
>>>
```

I would recommend using `random.choices` to select your random numbers from a collection/population of possible numbers. If you use `random.randint` to generate your numbers, you may end up with the same number appearing more than once in a given draw (as far as I know, any given numbered lottery ball does not appear more than once in a real lottery).